# knockout js selected object not being selected

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have this bit of html which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="if: selectedStyle">
    <label class="control-label">Style</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: styles, optionsText: 'Name', value: 'selectedStyle'"></select>
</div>
```

The styles are populated with an init function that looks like this:

```
function init() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var id = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    $.get(competitionsUrl)
        .done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, competition) {
                if (competition.Id === id) {
                    self.id(id);
                    self.name(competition.Name);
                    self.description(competition.Description);
                    self.styleId(competition.StyleId);
                    self.logoId(competition.LogoId);
                    self.backgroundImageId(competition.BackgroundImageId);

                    self.logo = new UploadViewModel("#logo", competition.Logo);
                    self.backgroundImage = new UploadViewModel("#backgroundImage", competition.BackgroundImage);
                } else {
                    ids.push(competition.Id);
                }
            });
        })
        .always(function () {
            self.loadingCompetitions(false);
        })
        .fail(common.handleError);

    $.get(stylesUrl)
        .done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, style) {
                self.styles.push(style);
            });
        })
        .always(function () {
            self.loadingStyles(false);
        })
        .fail(common.handleError);
}
```

Then I created this **subscribe** method to handle the **selectedStyle**:

```
self.loading.subscribe(function (loading) {
    if (!loading) {
        var styles = self.styles();

        for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            var style = styles[i];

            if (style.Id === self.styleId()) {
                console.log(style);
                self.selectedStyle(style);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The **console.log(style)** returns the correct style, but the style actually selected is the first style in the list :(

Also worth noting, is that I set up a test:

```
self.selectedStyle.subscribe(function (style) {
    console.log("changed");
    console.log(style);
});
```

which fires after the first subscription and again shows the correct style, but when I change the dropdown selection, it does not fire.

Anyone got any idea what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the value as literal string and you should pass it as "object"

try removing the quotes of `selectedStyle`

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="if: selectedStyle">
    <label class="control-label">Style</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: styles, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedStyle"></select>
</div>
```